# Conditional Factor Level Selection in Aggregation of Data Table

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to aggregate a `data.table` to 1 row per ID.

Suppose the first column represents ID and the last column is the factor of interest:

```
mydt <- data.table(matrix(c(1,2,"Level 1", 1,12,"Level 0", 1,12,"Level 0", 2,12,"Level 3", 2,12,"Level 2"), nrow = 5, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE))
mydt
   V1 V2      V3
1:  1  2 Level 1
2:  1 12 Level 0
3:  1 12 Level 0
4:  2 12 Level 3
5:  2 12 Level 2
```

I have non-intuitive rules for how to aggregate the factor:

- if `Level 1` exists for any row of ID then the aggregated row should have `Level 1` for that ID
- if not, then if `Level 2` exists for that ID then use it
- if not, then `Level 3` if it exists
- if not, then `Level 0`

The actual `data.table` is very large and there is no numeric component of the actual factor levels, they are just strings. This script will be run at least once per day, so I'm trying to avoid slow pre-processing with loops.

The desired result would look like this:

```
   V1 V2      V3
1:  1  8.67 Level 1
2:  2 12 Level 2
```

However I can't find an suitable aggregation function...

```
mydt[,.(V2 = mean(V2, na.rm = T), V3 = if("Level 1") "Level 1" else if("idk help me out?")), by = "V1"]
```

Comment: I assume your data is not stored as `character` initially (that you're using `mean(V2)` without `as.numeric` suggests this is the case)? using `matrix` to declare your example removes the non-`character` types when mixing. Better to specify column-wise, e.g. `mydt <- data.table(V1 = rep(1:2, c(3,2)), V2 = rep(c(2, 12), c(1, 4)), V3 = factor(paste0("Level", c(1,0,0,3,2))))`

Comment: Yeah, what Michael said: Don't use a matrix for mixed data types (strings and numbers in this case). You can also do `mydt = rbindlist(list( list(1,2,"Level 0"), list(1,12,"Level 0"), list(1,12,"Level 0"), list(2,12,"Level 3"), list(2,12,"Level 2") ))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can convert 'V3'  to `factor` with `levels` specified in the specified order.

```
mydt[, V3:= factor(V3, levels=c('Level 1', 'Level 2', 'Level 3',
 'Level 0'))][, list(V2= mean(as.numeric(V2)),
                     V3= V3[which.min(V3)]) , V1]
#   V1        V2      V3
#1:  1  8.666667 Level 1
#2:  2 12.000000 Level 2
```

---

Or another option is `match` to get the numeric index by matching with a vector (arranged in a specific order), get the index of minimum value, get the correpondng 'V3' value, grouped by 'V1'.  As for 'V2', it is just the `mean` of 'V2' (The example showed in the OP's post had the 'V2' column as 'character' class - so have to wrap `as.numeric`).

```
lvls <- paste('Level', c(1:3, 0))
mydt[, list(V2= mean(as.numeric(V2)), 
             V3= V3[which.min(match(V3, lvls))]) , V1]
```

Answer (score 3):

I would specify `V3` as a factor with your specified order and simply order by `V3` to do the rest:

```
mydt[ , V3 := factor(V3, paste("Level", c(1:3, 0)))]

mydt[order(V3), V3 := V3[1L], by = V1][]
   V1 V2      V3
1:  1  2 Level 1
2:  1 12 Level 1
3:  1 12 Level 1
4:  2 12 Level 2
5:  2 12 Level 2
```

If you're aggregating to a smaller table, this works:

```
mydt[order(V3), .(V2 = mean(as.numeric(V2), na.rm = TRUE),
                      V3 = V3[1L]), by = V1]
   V1        V2      V3
1:  1  8.666667 Level 1
2:  2 12.000000 Level 2
```

---

Note that due to a peculiarity of how GForce works in `data.table`, the following (originally suggested by @Frank and much more in the spirit of @akrun's approach) is an error (in current versions, at least):

```
mydt[, .(V2 = mean(as.numeric(V2), na.rm = TRUE),
         V3 = min(V3)), by = V1]
```

But this is not:

```
mydt[, V2 := as.numeric(V2)][, .(V2 = mean(V2, na.rm = TRUE),
                                 V3 = min(V3)), by = V1]
```

Basically, the latter case uses `gmin`, `data.table`'s internally optimized `min` function, which works on `factor`s, while the former, since at least one call is not *directly* to a GForce function, appeals to `base` `min`, which does not work on `factor`s (*cf* `min(factor(1:3))`).

Since I take it you actually have `V2` stored as `numeric` in the first place in your data, perhaps the `min` approach is better.

Comment: @akrun it is (hard to see how this can be done effectively without setting `factor` order), but I prefer mine. `which.min` seems bound to be slower.

Comment: Dunno what akrun's comment was, but `DT[order(x), x[1]]` seems like a convoluted way of arriving at `min(x)`..? I mean like `mydt[, .(V2 = mean(V2), V3 = min(V3)), by=V1]` (assuming V2 was earlier converted to numeric).

Comment: And yet it does for me...? I'll show details in chat.

Comment: @akrun Okay, maybe it is a 1.9.7 feature. I don't see it in the NEWS, though.